# How to create a custom template to admin dashboard

Tags: theme-development, customization, wp-admin, dashboard, network-admin

I was trying to create a template to customize my WP admin dashboard, not only a css mod but a entirely renew to my customers.

I've successfully created a page template for a custom login page, and it worked fine, but now, the biggest problem is how to redirect admin pages to custom ones? And plus, how to call admin functions on this page?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Codex has documentation on creating custom login pages - [Customize Login Form > Make Custom Login Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form#Make_a_Custom_Login_Page), using [`wp_login_form()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_login_form/) function. This should load everything necessary to log user in.

However, unlike login, replacing admin would be much more involved and have many approaches. Typically to access admin function in non-admin context admin PHP files have to be loaded manually which is rather fragile and prone to errors on WordPress version updates.

Comment: Hi @Rarst, Thanks for comment. You are right, I've a total custom login page, however, using wp_signon with a ajax call, that worked fine.

I also thought in a ajax solution to admin dashboard, just like a <iframe> to grab things from wp admin and skin it using this same ajax call to looks like my new base stylesheet, but it involves a lot of ajax call and replacement, it will considerably slow down everything...

I'm developing it in a localhost, and it works fine, but I'm sure that in live it will be a turtle..

I'm trying to figure out another way...